# MVC - Ajax post the contents inside all div tags that exists inside the view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using MVC3 in my project.

I have a view with around 2-12 div tags it depends on how many questions there is, if there is 5 questions there is 5 div tags that looks like an answer form. all these div tags are inside one form.

Each div tag have a hiddenfield, textarea and a DropDownList. values inside those fields are used by ajax post that takes the values inside the fields and posts it to my controller.

So far I am able to post the first div tag with my code, but the rest of the div tags aint getting posted. What I am looking for is to be able to post all the div tags one by one when "save all" button is clicked. Also all the div tags have the same class name: "wizard-step2". They all also have a ID which is unique and the value of the ID is the QuestionID taken from the database.

Here is my jquery code for the post:

```
$("saveall").click(function() {
        $('#loading2').show();
        setTimeout(function () { $("#loading2").hide(); }, 400);
        var $step = $(".wizard-step2"); // show all steps
        var Comment = $step.find(".Comment").val();
        var QuestionID = $step.find(".QuestionID").val();
        var Grade = $step.find(".Grade").val();

        var data =
            {
                Comment: Comment,
                QuestionID: QuestionID,
                Grade: Grade
            };
        $.post('@Url.Action("AnswerForm", "AnswerNKI")', data, function () {

        });
    });
```

The following code will only save the first div tag but not the rest.

this is my HTML:

```
@{
                int nr = 1;
                foreach (SelectedQuestionViewModel items in Model.AllSelectedQuestions)
                {
                <div class="wizard-step2" id="@items.QuestionID">
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <p>@(nr++).&nbsp;@items.SelectedQuestionText <span class="b">Betyg:&nbsp;&nbsp;
                   @{
                    var selectListItems = (new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }).Select(i => new SelectListItem { Text = i.ToString(), Value = i.ToString(), Selected = (items.Grade.HasValue && i == items.Grade.Value) });

                     @Html.DropDownList("selectetListItems", selectListItems, "n/a", new { @class = "Grade" })
                    }</span></p>

                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.TextArea("Comment", items.Comment, new { @id = "selectstyle3", @class = "Comment" })
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    @Html.Hidden("QuestionID", items.QuestionID, new { @id = "SelectedQuestions", @class = "QuestionID" })
                    <br/>
                </div>
                }
 }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please post your HTML structure.

Comment: I have updated with my HTML structure

Comment: @RammtinAvar, try to use my solution, I have used that for master details...

Comment: not relevant to your question but i think that this is much easier sol http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function to iterate over the divs, and send an AJAX post for each individual one. Without seeing the HTML structure I can only guess based on what you already had, but I think the following should work:

```
$("saveall").click(function() {
    $('#loading2').show();
    setTimeout(function () { $("#loading2").hide(); }, 400);
    $(".wizard-step2").each(function(index, step) {
        var Comment = step.find(".Comment").val();
        var QuestionID = step.find(".QuestionID").val();
        var Grade = step.find(".Grade").val();
        var data = {
            Comment: Comment,
            QuestionID: QuestionID,
            Grade: Grade
        };
        $.post('@Url.Action("AnswerForm", "AnswerNKI")', data, function () {

        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one... it will collect all your divs into one single array, and using ajax post will post the data...

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function () {
        var o = {};
        var a = this.serializeArray();
        $.each(a, function () {
            if (o[this.name]) {
                if (!o[this.name].push) {
                    o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                }
                o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
            } else {
                o[this.name] = this.value || '';
            }
        });
        return o;
    };

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Submit").click(function () {
        var QuestionAnswerArray = [];
        var QuestionAnswerLength = $(".wizard-step2").length;
        $(".wizard-step2").each(function (i) {
            var test = $(this).find("select,textarea, input").serializeObject()
            QuestionAnswerArray.push(test);
            if ((i + 1) == QuestionAnswerLength) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/../AnswerNKI/AnswerForm',
                    data: JSON.stringify(QuestionAnswerArray),
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (return_flag) {                            
                        if (return_flag == true) {
                            alert("Question and Answers Saved Succesfully!");                                
                        } else {
                            alert("Error Occured");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

and in your controller...

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AnswerForm(Answers[] answers)
{
                foreach (var item in answers)
                {
                    // do whatever you want here
                }
                return View();
}
```

Comment: I dont see why I should collect all divs to one single array? Each div tag is already an array all I need is to be able to step each one of them and post.

Comment: if you want to post each div separately, then the other posted solution by @Anthony Grist will do, but if you want to post only single time for all the divs my solution will do that..

Answer (score 0):

I had to do a for loop this is the correct answer:

```
var $step = $(".wizard-step2"); // get current step
            for (var i = 0; i < $step.length; i++) {

                var allsteps = $(".wizard-step2");
                var Allsteps = $(allsteps[i]);
                var Comment = Allsteps.find(".Comment").val();
                var QuestionID = Allsteps.find(".QuestionID").val();
                var Grade = Allsteps.find(".Grade").val();

                var data =
                {
                    Comment: Comment,
                    QuestionID: QuestionID,
                    Grade: Grade
                };
                $.post('@Url.Action("AnswerForm", "AnswerNKI")', data, function () {

                    if (Comment != null && Grade > 0) {
                        $('a[data-id="' + QuestionID + '"]').removeClass("unfinished");
                        $('a[data-id="' + QuestionID + '"]').addClass("completed");
                    } else {
                        $('a[data-id="' + QuestionID + '"]').removeClass("completed");
                        $('a[data-id="' + QuestionID + '"]').addClass("unfinished");

                    }

                });
            }
```